# Should I say "rules of here" or "rules here"?

Tags: adverbs

For example, should I ask "Do you know the rules of here?" or "... the rules here?"

I believe the latter is correct but I did see some people use the former, got confused :-(

Comment: In principle, following the pattern of *Do you know the rules of cricket?* and *Do you know the rules of/in/at my house?*, you might suppose you should include ***of***. But in fact, native speakers never do this with *Do you know **the rules here**?*

Comment: The adverb *here* replaces a prepositional phrase *of this place* or something.  Similarly, *He went to Spain" becomes "He went there" not "He went to there".

Answer (score 1):

Yes the latter is correct. "here" is somehow never quite used as a noun in English, and so "of here" is automatically grammatically incorrect. Instead, "here" is used as an adverb of place, and so as GEdgar noted it stands for one of "of/in/at/to this place", depending on the usage. Here (in your question), "the rules here" means "the rules of/at this place", which may imply "the rules among us" if referring to joining or participating in a group.